# Use ActiveObject to select recipient in Word (JScript, Javascript)

Tags: excel, ms-word, jscript, active-objects

how can I select an recpient in Word with the ActiveObject function in JScript or Javascript?
Can I only translate the VBA code to an JScript or Javascript Code?

Here my code start fragment:

```
var objWord;
objWord = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
objWord.Visible = true;
objWord.Workbooks.Open(//file Path);
```

I tested the cell function in Excel that works perfect. But are there options to select an recipient in word?

Comment: What is "_recipient_" in the context of the question?

Comment: I want to add a recipient to the word file with the ActiveXObject

Comment: Yes, but what is that recipient in the sense of code? Is it just a string you want to the content (perhaps in a specific place), or is it an object or something else?

Comment: Yes, I would like to print labels and I need the excel file with the data.